# WebStorm code completion for Node shows too many options

Tags: node.js, typescript, webstorm

I've created a small project with NodeJS and TypeScript code. Installed the type definition files there (tsd install node). The code starts with these lines:

`var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(...)`

When I open this code in WebStorm 11 it shows me hundreds of options in a context-sensitive help window when I hit CTRL-Space after http.

I tried adding `/// <reference path="typings/node/node.d.ts" />` as the first line, downloaded and installed DefinitelyTyped community stub, but it still shows tons of options for the http object.

When I open the same file in Visual Studio Code, it shows me a short list of API related to Node's http module. How to teach WebStorm to be smarter with code completion?

Comment: Maybe this should be a bug/suggestion here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB

Comment: I will, just wanted to make sure that it's not something that I missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried adding ///  as the first line, downloaded and installed DefinitelyTyped community stub, but it still shows tons of options for the http object.

This is because you are using `var/require`. This means that webstorm is being *heuristic* in its suggestions. You should use `import/require` to narrow it down to *just what is actually declared for the http module*:

```
import http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(...)
```

More on `import` : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/modules.html